# Renaming computers with a CSV file

Tags: powershell, csv, rename, host, hostname

I need some assistance as to how I can rename pcs in bulk with a powershell script and a csv file. I will need to achieve this via Kaseya (VSA) which manages our Windows devices. Here is how I am thinking of achieving this:

1. Filter all agents in VSA and export them in a CSV file.
2. In that CSV file there will be two columns; "currenthostname" & "newhostname"
3. I will insert the newhostname column and manually type in the hostnames
4. Upload the csv file with the newly added "newhostname" column
5. Kaseya will push the csv file out to all the hosts into the "C:\kworking" directory
6. I will need to assemble a script that imports the csv file and searches for the current hostname of the machine under the currenthostname column; if there is a match, then the machine will need to be renamed to the new hostname corresponding to the currenthostname column.

Step 6 is where I am having trouble and would like any insight anyone can provide. Here is what my script looks like so far:

```
    $hostnames = Import-Csv "C:\kworking\hostnames.csv"

    foreach ($hostname in $hostnames) {
    $currentname = $hostname.oldName
    $newname = $hostname.newName 
    $pcname = hostname
    if ($pcname -match $currentname) {
        Write-Host "Renaming computer from: $pcname to: $newname" 
        rename-computer -newname $newname
    }
    }
```

[image: Here is what my CSV file looks like]

[image: Here is what the powershell output looks like after running the code:]

Comment: So what exactly is failing with your current code?

Comment: To add to Santiago's comment: there's no obvious problem with your code, except that you should `-eq`, not `-match` (the latter is for _regex_-based matching).

Comment: So your question is related to how to avoid that message / accept without confirming or to understand why you get that message ?

Comment: @SantiagoSquarzon So the issue is that my code is dysfunctional. here is what I am trying to achieve.

1) Have the computer look through the "current name" column and find its name.
2) Once the computer finds its name, it looks at the corresponding value in the new name column and the computer should rename itself to match what is in the newname column.

The name of the computer is "whattheheck1" which isnt in the current name column so it should even be attempting to rename in the first place.

Comment: I see, well thats kind of weird but I don't see an issue with your code, try it using this code, `Import-Csv ... | ? CurrentName -EQ $env:COMPUTERNAME | Select-Object -Expand newName | Rename-Computer`

Comment: Check the header line in the CSV - in the screenshot, the CSV header is `currentname` and `newname`, but your script is referencing `$currentname = $hostname.**oldName**`

Answer (score 1):

How long are your computer names? Max length is 63 characters,  with only (a-z), (A-Z), number (0-9), and hyphen (-) characters permitted. No spaces, dots or number-only names.

The easiest way is to keep the names to 15 chars or less so you can be sure there are no dupes. Or use the `-force` parameter to accept whatever NETBIOS name it autogenerates (which you now have no record of, but it doesn't matter too much most of the time).

I'd also recommend including the `-Restart` parameter to keep it consistent. Naturally it won't restart if the command fails.